# Ruby .slice_when is there a way to slice an array when 3 characters in a row are equal?

Tags: ruby

Part of a problem I am trying to solve is taking a number and finding when it has 3 numbers in a row. I've attempted two ways to do this and both have not worked according to plan.

In the number 451999277, 999 would be three numbers in a row and the desired output.

```
#first bit of code worked for 451999277, but did not work with the number 10560002 
#which should return 000 but I am left with an empty array []

array2 = []
array = num1.to_s.chars
array.map {|x| array2 << x if x == array[array.index(x) + 1] && x == array[array.index(x) + 2]}


#I then tried to use .slice_when which also did not work.

num1.to_s.chars.slice_when{ |x, y, z| x == y && x == z}.to_a
```

Is there a better way to do this? Including something I have not tried? The first bit of code seems to work for a lot of inputs, but again not 10560002.

This is an edit...I am realizing now that the .index is probably returning the first index where x occurs....in this 10560002...it would be index 1...still looking for a solution.

Edit again, figured it out!

```
array2 = []
array = num1.to_s.chars
array.each_with_index.map {|x, i| array2 << x if x == array[i + 1] && x == array[i + 2]}
```

Comment: "...and finding when it has 3 numbers in a row."  That needs to be clarified. Firstly, the answer to that is `true` or `false`. Do you that or do you want all qualifying substrings? Secondly, I believe you are referring to three *digits* in a row that are the same digit (e.g., `444`, whereas `232323` contains the same three *numbers* in a row).  Do you want *exactly* three digits in a row that are the same digit, or three or more? This may seem picky, but being precise when setting out a code specification is of utmost importance.

Answer (score 3):

```
>> 451999277.to_s.chars.chunk(&:itself).select{|_, a| a.size == 3}.map(&:first)
=> ["9"]
```

- `chunk` finds consecutive elements that evaluate to the same value
- `select` allows you to take only the subsequences of length 3

Answer (score 1):

```
r = /
    (\d)     # match a digit in capture group 1
    (\1{2,}) # match two or more digit that equal the contents of capture group 1,
             # in capture group 2
    /x       # free-spacing regex definition mode.

n = 239994566666

n.to_s.scan(r).map { |a| a.join.to_i }
  #=> [999, 66666]
```

The steps are as follows.

```
s = n.to_s
  #=> "239994566666" 
b = s.scan(r)
  #=> [["9", "99"], ["6", "6666"]] 
b.map { |a| a.join.to_i }
  #=> [999, 66666]
```

See the doc for [String#scan](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-scan), particularly the treatment of capture groups. Capture group 1 is needed to capture that first digit that is to be repeated. In order for scan to return `\1{2,}` we need to put that in a second capture group.

Answer (score 1):

```
num.to_s.split('').each_cons(3){|x,y,z| print x,y,z if x==y && y==z }

#if num = 451999277 => output: 999
#if num = 10560002 => output: 000
```

First, split num in Array # `num.to_s.split('')` => ["4", "5", "1", "9", "9", "9", "2", "7", "7"]

get 3 value # `num.to_s.split('').each_cons(3)` => *451 519 199 999 992 927 277*

and print pair of 3 where all values are equal => *999*

Note: you can use *return* instead of *print* if you are using it in a function.